# Problem with mysql (mariadb) crash

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

An hour ago I noticed that the mysql (mariadb 5.2.5) server is not running on my debian VPS. So I immediately ran "/etc/init.d/mysql restart" and it started just fine. Here's what the daemon log says about mariadb when it had crashed

```
Apr 23 11:58:15 slides mysqld_safe: Number of processes running now: 0
Apr 23 11:58:15 slides mysqld_safe: mysqld restarted
Apr 23 11:58:21 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:21 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is     deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server'     instead.
Apr 23 11:58:21 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:21 [Warning] '--default-collation' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--collation-server' instead.
Apr 23 11:58:26 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 131006464 bytes)
Apr 23 11:58:26 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 98254848 bytes)
Apr 23 11:58:27 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:27 [Note] PrimeBase XT (PBXT) Engine 1.0.11-7 Pre-GA loaded...
Apr 23 11:58:27 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:27 [Note] Paul McCullagh, PrimeBase Technologies GmbH, http://www.primebase.org
Apr 23 11:58:28 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:28 [Note] The server was not shutdown correctly, recovery required
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:29  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: InnoDB: mmap(272171008 bytes) failed; errno 12
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:29InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate the memory for the buffer pool
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: InnoDB
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:29 [ERROR] Aborting
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 
Apr 23 11:58:29 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:29 [Note] PrimeBase XT Engine shutdown...
Apr 23 11:58:30 slides mysqld: 110423 11:58:30 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Apr 23 11:58:30 slides mysqld: 
Apr 23 11:58:31 slides mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I just need to be absolutely sure I understand everything that's going on here. The thing mysqld_safe saw that mysql isn't running and tried to restart it, right? But there was a problem with memory?

What does this line mean? `InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M` It tried to allocate 256MB or just informing about the size? I'm not actively using InnoDB either.

Comment: Could you post the results off `ulimit -a` and `free -m`?

Comment: I restarted the server after that, I think I found where the problem is. A memory leak in a software I run on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check for the amount of free memory in your server.